# Pushing UIViewController in navigationcontroller shows empty view

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I am facing the problem that when I push my viewcontroller in the navigationcontroller all it does is changing the navigationbar and showing the standard background but no view is to be seen. My code for pushing the viewcontroller into the navigationcontroller looks like:

```
Viewcontroller1 *viewController = [[Viewcontroller1 alloc] autorelease];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

But, if I initialise the viewcontroller by creating IBOutlets for it, it works just fine. But the reason why I am not doing that is because I later on needs to pass some parameters to the class on initialization.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You are totally abusing the system doing this - no wonder you have huge problems. You should create the object normally. The view controller does not call viewDidLoad until someone accesses its view property, so you have lots of opportunity to configure properties BEFORE you then go and push it.

Comment: Okay, I am new to ios programming this so wasn't aware of that. Thanks. But what do you exactly mean by creating the object normally ?

Comment: [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNib:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];

Comment: obvious error is absence of `init` (or `init`-like initialized) after `alloc`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to initialise your view like

if you have xib then

```
Viewcontroller1 *viewController = [[[Viewcontroller1 alloc] initWithNibName:@"Viewcontroller1" bundle:nil]autorelease];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

if you haven't xib

```
Viewcontroller1 *viewController = [[[Viewcontroller1 alloc] init]autorelease];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: I already tried that and wont work neither. All the Viewcontrollers are within the same xib.

It gives the exception:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Viewcontroller1 initWithNibName:]:

Comment: Using your seconds method, with just "init" results in a blank page without the view but just the navigationbar.

Comment: check with this line viewController.title=@"View"; add this line before navigation and after initialization. if you get the title view in your navigation that means it navigate to ViewController1

Comment: It does give the proper title. So yes it navigates, but doesn't show any view.

Comment: can you post your ViewController's viewDidload method?

Comment: It is just empty. Should it initialize the view or something that will make it appear ? Sorry, I am pretty new to this kind of programming.

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

Comment: hmmn that's why you get blank view controller. check with background color property of view so you can check that view is load.     self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];

Comment: Setting my background to yellow in the viewDidLoad does indeed work. Is there any way I can make it load the view, that the interface builder has attached to the viewcontroller?

Comment: As I just posted before, except of I now added yellow background..
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
 self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
}

Comment: you have a xib or not for this view controller ?

Comment: They are in the main xib where all my viewcontrollers are, MainWindow_iPhone.xib
Do I need to create a new xib for this to work properly ?

Comment: it's not compulsory  to make xib. if you have a very less design. can you upload your code so i can check because i can't understand without seen your code

Comment: You eventually got any mail or smth I could sent it to?

Comment: Hmm I will see if I can find any solution by using it with assigning it with IBOutlets instead, that seemed to work.. 
Thank you very very much for your help. It is wonderful with people like you that are willing to spent time on newbies like me :)